# Prove by induction that $2^n > n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Show that $2^n > n^2$ through induction and so far I got to the $k+1$ step, but I am stuck.

I have $2^{k+1} = 2 +2^k$, but I don`t know how the book turned it into $k^2 +k^2$. The book then follows to turn it into $k^2+4n$ and then $k^2+2k+1$. Was the $K$th step used because I cant understand how it was used in case.

Comment: Note that $2^{k+1} = 2\cdot 2^k \neq 2+2^k$.  Now, $$\underbrace{k^2+k^2}_{\large = 2k^2}$$ $2k^2$ means we have two of k^2$'s; i.e., 2k^2$

Comment: How do we get to the 2k+1 from k^2?

Comment: Note that $k^2 \gt 2k+1$ for all $k\gt 2$. This can be proven by a very simple and short induction on k, if you're not convinced.

Comment: Note that is not true for $\,n=4,\,$ so you probably forgot a hypothesis that $\, n\ge 5.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inductive hypothesis: For $n = k$, $$\color{blue}{2^k \geq k^2},\quad k \geq 4.$$

$$2^{k+1} = 2\cdot \color{blue}{2^k} \geq 2(\color{blue}{k^2}) \geq k^2 + k^2 \geq k^2 + 2k + 1 \overset{\large k>2} = (k+1)^2$$

Comment: is 2^k supposed to equal n^2 in this case allowing us to.replace

Comment: Since we have assumed $2^k \geq k^2$ (inductive hypotheis), it follows  that $2\cdot 2^k \geq 2\cdot k^2$. We simply have the inductive hypothesis (inequality), multiplied by $2$ on each side of the inequality.

Comment: how.did k^2 turn into 2k +1

Comment: $k^2 \gt 2k + 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$, $k\gt 2$. Since we are proving what holds for $k \geq 4$, it follows that we're safe in asserting that $k^2>2k + 1$.

Comment: what i mean is, how did you figure out it was 2k +1. How did.you get it.

Comment: Remember our objective is to show $2^{k+1}\geq (n+1)^2$. And $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$. So by showing that $k^2 + k^2 \geq k^2 + 2k + 1$, we proven our objective: $2^{k+1} \geq 2k^2 \geq (n+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Induction problems like this can be done *mechanically* by *telescopy*. Rewriting $\,f(n) = 2^n-n^2\,$ as a telescopic sum of its differences makes its positivity obvious, because each summand is $\color{#c00}{\ge 0}.$

$$\displaystyle\begin{eqnarray}n\ge 5\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ f(n) &=&\!  f(5)\,+ \sum_{\large k\,=\,5}^{\large n-1}\ (f(k\!+\!1)-f(k))\\ 
\displaystyle\Rightarrow\ \ \ 2^n-n^2 &=& \ 7\ +\ \sum_{\large k\,=\,5}^{\large n-1}\, (\overbrace{2^{k}- (2k\!+\!1)}^{\large \color{#c00}{\ge 0}})\, >\, 0 \end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

That the overbraced term is $\color{#c00}{\ge 0}\,$ is obvious by induction (telescopic or not).  Note that it fails for $\,n < 5,\,$ e.g. $\,f(4) = 0,\ f(3) = -1.\ $

For further discussion see my [many posts on telescopic induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy)

Comment: It'd be more complete if the overbraced term is shown to be greater or equal to zero by telescoping induction. This will highlight the fact that this method is powerful because it reduces a harder induction problem to smaller, simpler ones.